# Sound setting opens and then shuts immediately

Tags: system, sound

When I click on the Sound setting it begins to open the panel but then immediately shuts down the System Settings panel.

I think this behaviour started after I installed Pulse Audio dlna and Pulse Audio Volume Control.

I have tried reinstalling the Sound system setting, but this makes no difference to the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue since long time, even sometimes you just load-module reacts same way, Simple way to fix it make sure your dlna module is disabled in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` just comment it if not commented. Let me know if that doesn't work I'll provide `default.pa` file